# Issue with input tag in Office add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Recently we faced an issue with Outlook Web Add-in on Microsoft Outlook for Mac.

We use an `input` HTML tag for choosing files, and it turns out, that multiple file selection doesn't work on Microsoft Outlook for Mac.

It works as expected in Internet Explorer, in Microsoft Office 2016 for Windows, and in Safari. The HTML5 source code for the tag is:

```html
<input type="file" multiple />
```

It can be reproducible by creating an Outlook Web Add-in from default Visual Studio 2017 template and adding a new input as specified above.

- Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit: 1607 (14393.1715)
- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017: 15.3.5 (26730.16)
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 11: 11.1715.14393.0
- Microsoft Outlook 2016 64-bit: 16.0.4549.100
- Apple macOS Sierra: 10.12.6 (16G29)
- Apple Safari: 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7)
- Microsoft Outlook for Mac: 15.38 (170902)

Any ideas how to fix / workaround this?

**UPDATE 10/30/2017:**

HTML source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" multiple />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share some code. In it's current form your question is very difficult to answer.

Comment: Kindly provide the html code snippet you are using.